# Notification dose not occur on selected time

Tags: java, android, set, android-notifications, android-timepicker

I want to set notification when user selects time. So I have added time picker dialog. I have set time with calendar.

But I am not getting any notification though I have set time. I have 3 time picker dialog as I am setting start time and end time for event and now I want to set notification time.

When I am setting notification time the same time is getting set on end time.

This is the code to set time :

```
 @Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {

        case TIME_DIALOG_ID:

            // set time picker as current time
            return new TimePickerDialog(this, timePickerListener, hour, minute,
                    false);

        case TIME_DIALOG:

            // set time picker as current time

            return new TimePickerDialog(this, timePickerListener, hour, minute,
                    false);

        case TIME:

            return new TimePickerDialog(this, timePickerListener, hour, minute,
                    false);
    }
    return null;
}

private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minutes) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        hour = hourOfDay;
        minute = minutes;

        updateTime(hour, minute);

    }

};


// Used to convert 24hr format to 12hr format with AM/PM values
private void updateTime(int hour, int minute) {

    df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a");

    if (timeType == 0) {

        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        c.set(Calendar.DATE, day);

        datefrom = c.getTime();
        startTime = String.valueOf(datefrom);
        aTime = df.format(datefrom.getTime());
        showFromTime.setText(aTime);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(datefrom), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else if (timeType == 1) {

        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        c.set(Calendar.DATE, day);

        dateto = c.getTime();
        endTime = String.valueOf(dateto);
        bTime = df.format(dateto.getTime());
        showToTime.setText(bTime);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(dateto), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    else
    {
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        c.set(Calendar.DATE, day);
        notification = c.getTime();
        notificationTime = df.format(notification);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),notificationTime,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Notification service class

```
    public class NotificationReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver {


    private static final int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;
    NotificationManager notificationManager;
    Notification myNotification;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Time is set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context,
                0,
                myIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle("Event Time")
                .setContentText("Time")
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alarm_black_48dp)
                .build();

        notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, myNotification);
    }

}
```

EDIT : SET ALARM FUNCTION

```
  @SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void setAlarm(Calendar targetmCalen) {

    AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    PendingIntent alarmIntent;
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationReceiver.class);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
            "call alarmManager.setExact()",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,targetmCalen.getTimeInMillis(),
            1000 * 60 * 20, alarmIntent);

    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(),NotificationReceiver.class);
    PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();

    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);


    //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Notification Set",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Please help..

Comment: Oh, surprise! You didn't read the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)! Specially, where it says: `Note: Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use.` And it also provides a walkthrogh.

Comment: Tried to use setExact(),,still No notification. @Hrundi V. Bakshi

Comment: Depending on your current OS version, either use `set()` or `setExact()`

Comment: Yes I tried using both. Still no notification.

Comment: Anythng wrong in my calender instance ? or while I am setting time?

Comment: Debug. Debug. Debug. Print the values and see if they match the values you're expecting.

Comment: I did debug and got values as expected but no notification yet.. I am saving only hours and mins in database do i need to save whole date string?

Comment: It should work for "today". If the time is past, then it will fire immediately. But it will not repeat for tomorrow.

Comment: Its not at all getting fired.

Comment: You must wait until the time is due. Or set your device time close to the time you have choosen. Alternatively, try setting also the year, month, and day.

Comment: Obviously i wait till the time comes. Time passes still alarm dose not raise.

Comment: There can be different causes. Is the receiver declared in the manifest?

Comment: Yes I have not declared it in manifest. But after declaring also no changes.

Comment: Well, there's probably some little bit of code which does not fit perfectly. Try to follow the repeating alarm example found on the android.developer site. It works beautifully. Another beautiful piece of code you might find interesting is TaskButler.

Comment: nice example..Helped a lot. Thank you..

Comment: I am now getting notification on the set time but also I get notification when I click on save as the set alarm method gets called. I am updating my set alarm method in question. Can you please check and let me know?

Comment: Well, this would be time consuming, My advice is to have a look at the TaskButler source.